# All SD Cards mount as Internal

Tags: macos, usb, disk-utility

I don't know why but recently all SD cards mount as Internal on my Mac

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

PS. Only SD cards mount as Internal all pen drives mount as external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behavior and how all Macs with built-in SD card readers are treated by the OS.

If you want to split hairs it is indeed "internal" as the card itself is inserted **into** the Mac, even though a bit of it still stacks out.

Regardless of that it is still expected behavior and not a problem. As to why? well only Apple hardware and software engineers can give you a definitive answer on that and they aren't allowed to say